# Error When Trying to Sort Google Sheets Worksheet in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to sort a worksheet (i.e. `single tab`) within a large Google Sheets workbook using Python. However, I am getting an error when executing the request:

> "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "sort_range": Cannot find field."

The Python snippet:

```
SORT_AMEX_PLAT = {
      "sortRange": {
          "sheetId": AMEX_PLAT_SHEET_ID,
          "startRowIndex": 1,
          "endRowIndex": 20000,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 30,
          "sortSpecs": [
              {
                "dimensionIndex": 0,
                "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"
              }
          ]
        }
    }

    sortRequest = sheet.values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=SORT_AMEX_PLAT)
    sortResponse = sortRequest.execute()
```

Comment: looks like your error has nothing to do with the code you posted.  Perhaps you could post all relevant code.

Comment: It clearly does have something to do with the code I posted since the sheets API is unable to process the JSON that the SORT_AMEX_PLAT variable gets sent as.

Comment: "sheet" isn't defined in your code.  Given the error is coming from function calls related to sheet, it's very difficult to guess what you are doing incorrectly.  That being said, your SORT_AMEX_PLAT dict doesn't match the format provided by the sorting documentation:https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data

Comment: You're using the wrong API endpoint - you're using [`spreadsheets.values#batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) when you should be using [`spreadsheets#batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate). Note that the syntax of the method parameters is not equivalent between the two so you will need to ensure you are using the proper keyword arguments.